# iterate 2 arrays to update rails database table

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, for-loop

ruby on rails

i want to update the table **Fruit** in my database, using information stored in 2 arrays:

```
fruit_id=[2,8,14,35]
fruit_name=["apple","orange","banana","melon"]
```

so for example: **Fruit.id** 2 will have **Fruit.name** to be "apple"

i thought of for loop:

```
for i in fruit_id do
Fruit.find(i).update(name:fruit_name)
end
```

but that only made sense in my head.... 
i also apologize if this question had already been answered, im new to this and dont know the exact term to search for.... thanks alot!

Comment: Prior to asking you should research this a lot, try things, a lot, then do those things again, a lot. Currently, you show no evidence of researching or of trying beyond a quick attempt. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
fruit_id.zip(fruit_name).each do |id, name|
  fruit = Fruit.find_by(id: id)
  fruit.update_attribute(:name, name) if fruit
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple of hints I can suggest:

1. Use [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#zip-method)
2. To reduce number of queries you can use [ActiveRecord::Relation#where](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) with [ActiveRecord::Relation#update_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all)

So resulting code will be

```
fruit_ids = [2, 8, 14, 35]
fruit_names = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'melon']
fruits = fruit_ids.zip(fruit_names) # => [[2, 'apple'], [8, 'orange'], [14, 'banana'], [35, 'mellon']]

fruits.each do |(id, name)|
  Fruit.where(id: id).update_all(name: name)
end
```

Caution: `update_all` does **not** trigger validations, so if it's a case for you it's better to use initial approach with `Fruit.find(id).update(name: name)`

Comment: Since you're passing a single object (the id as an Integer) `where` might seem confusing at first sight. The same with `update_all`. You're updating a single record, whereas `update_all` is often used to update many records at once. Nobody says you can't, but it'll make the intent easier to understand. Also, you can remove the parenthesis from the `each` block.